Torsion subgroup of abelian variety
While studying elliptic curves I came over the question, whether for an elliptic curve $E$ and an integer $n$, we have
\begin{equation}
(E[n])^k = E^k[n],
\end{equation}
where $E^k$ is the $k$-dimensional abelian variety given by the product of $k$ elliptic curves? The implication $\subseteq$ should be true I guess. However, I have never studied abelian varieties, hence I do not even know how the torsion of a general abelian variety looks like. Does $E^k$ have any additional torsion points? I am particulary interested in the case of elliptic curves over finite fields, where the torsion subgroup of elliptic curves is fully characterized.
Since I do not have much knowledge in this theory, a short answer is totally sufficient for me

Yes. In the simplest case where you mean the set of $n$-torsion points, just write down multiplication by $n$ on the product and look at its kernel. If you mean the scheme-theoretic torsion it's still true; you need to know that taking kernels commutes with taking products.
